# Traversing a fat32 file system

Tags: fat32, computer-forensics, directory-traversal

I have formatted a thumbdrive with Fat32 and placed a file in the root directory named sampleFile.txt and with the contents "oblique". I looked at the drive in Disk Investigator and I found in the RootDirSector: sector 4096 the following

```
0040  53 41 4D 50 4C 45 7E 31   S A M P L E ~ 1    83  65  77  80  76  69 126  49
0048  54 58 54 20 00 36 81 5B   T X T   . 6 . [    84  88  84  32   0  54 129  91
0050  2E 45 2E 45 00 00 89 5B   . E . E . . . [    46  69  46  69   0   0 137  91
0058  2E 45 03 00 07 00 00 00   . E . . . . . .    46  69   3   0   7   0   0   0
```

How do I find the location of the sector cluster where the actual data of the file is located? Here is some additional info:

```
Logical drive: G
Size: 3 Gb (popularly 3 Gb)
Logical sectors: 3889016
Bytes per sector: 1024
Sectors per Cluster: 8
Cluster size: 8192
File system: FAT32
Number of copies of FAT: 2
Sectors per FAT: 1899
Start sector for FAT1: 298
Start sector for FAT2: 2197
Root DIR Sector: 4096
Root DIR Cluster: 2
2-nd Cluster Start Sector: 4096
Ending Cluster: 485616
Media Descriptor: 248
Root Entries: 0
Heads: 255
Hidden sectors: 0
Backup boot sector: 6
Reserved sectors: 298
FS Info sector: 1
Sectors per track: 63
File system version: 0
SerialVolumeID: 4A95395B
Volume Label: NO NAME
```

Comment: You need to look at the file allocation table, not the directory entry for the filename. The (incomplete) directory entry you posted contains the starting cluster at offset 26 of the record.  That cluster in the File Allocation Table is used to follow the chain of clusters that represent the file in the data area.   There is not enough info from what you posted to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

The "Short File Name Entry" contains the starting cluster of the file. Because the test file is very small, it only requires a cluster disk space. 
In this case, 8192 bytes for a 7 byte string. So therefore, the FAT does not matter, because the file is not span multiple clusters. However, your file entry is incomplete. A FAT32 file name entry is 32 bytes long. 
Offset 1Ah contains the starting cluster (2 bytes length). If offset 14h (2 bytes length) contains a value, then 1Ah is the low word, 14h the high word of the starting cluster.

I'm not sure, but I think the system area is counted sector wise, the data area cluster wise. The data area begins after the fat2. Unusually, your disk has a sector size of 1024 bytes.